# How to distinguish between click and double click in an activity?

Tags: android, button, click, double-click

In my activity I would like to vibrate if I click once on a button, and do something else (for example closing the window with the button "close") if I click twice on it. I'm thinking of measuring the time between 2 clicks on a button and if it's less than a given intervall, then doing the given function, but I don't know how can I do that, and it may be too complicated.

I implemented the `OnFocusChangeListener` of the button after setting `Focusable` to false, and it can vibrate, but I don't have the solution of double click.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use onDoubleTapListener.
Here are examples:
http://android-journey.blogspot.com/2010/01/android-gestures.html